# jQuery to Find/Replace html text when not inside an html tag other than P, DIV, SPAN, TD

Tags: jquery, replace

I have an html text fragment that's part of the page's DOM that I need to run a find/replace on and I need some help figuring out the best way to create the find/replace function.

For example, I would like to take the contents of the dom object whose id="content" and run a find replace using a target search phrase.

I need the function to replace each instance of the phrase it finds in the content with "<b>The Phrase</b>", providing that the phrase does not appear inside of any tag other than a div, p, span or td tag, and return the replaced xhtml text.

Can I do this with jQuery dom traversal along with some replace method?

Comment: It's unclear as to whether you want to modify content that's already in the DOM or not.  You imply that you do, but then you say you're passing XHTML into your replace function?  That's a string, not part of the DOM.

Comment: Good point. The text comes from the DOM. I will edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I used to look for a search string.  The RegEx checks for text that does not belong to an HTML tag.  In the replace function `$&` references the string that was matched.

```
var rx = new RegExp('(?![^<]+>)' + searchString, 'gi');

$(this).html(function (i, html) {
   return html.replace(rx, '<b>$&</b>')
});
```

As for not belonging to any other HTML tags, you'll have to provide an example.  That's where it could get tricky.

Comment: Thanks! Here's an example where "my text" should be replaced > <p>This is "my text" and should be replaced"...

Comment: Here's an example where "my text" should NOT be replaced > <b>This is "my text" and should NOT be replaced since its already inside a b tag</b>...

Comment: Could you explain how it works? It does what I exactly need, but I don't understand.

Comment: @maectpo searchString is the text you are searching on.  We create a regular expression from it to ensure we aren't accidentally matching text inside HTML tags.  Next, we use JavaScript's replace function to find/replace all occurrences of your search string.  You can think of the $& token as a variable containing the text that was matched.  We used $& instead of searchString because we want the search to be case-insensitive.  If your search string is "cool", we want it to match "Cool", "cOoL", etc.  and we want to preserve the casing in our matches.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I asked bad question. I mean, how does regular expression work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want avoid `&nbsp;` , you can use this regex `(?![^<&]+[>;])`
Using John Strickler comment :

```
var rx = new RegExp('(?![^<&]+[>;])' + searchString, 'gi');

$(this).html(function (i, html) {
   return html.replace(rx, '<b>$&</b>')
});
```