# Find and replace HTML string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Links from the database are website titles and render on the page "[Interesting Article](http://nowhere.com/): Author" - but occasionally the link is a question "[Where's China?](http://nowhere.com): GoogleMaps". The `?:` looks silly so I wanted to replace the HTML `?</span>:` with `?</span>`.

Here is the jQuery I worked out:

`$('#relatedinfo ul li a').html().replace('?</span>:','?</span>');`

But this doesn't actually replace it in the DOM. How do I get that string to actually change the page?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#relatedinfo ul li a').html(function(index,html){
    return html.replace(/<\/span>(\:)/,'');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RRfFr/).

Or even:

```
$('#relatedinfo ul li a').text(function(index,text){
    return text.replace(':','');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RRfFr/1/).

An updated approach is to check that the last character in the `span` is in the array of `['?','!','.']` and, if it is, then to remove the `:` from the nextSibling's nodeValue:

```
$('#relatedinfo ul li a span').text(function(index,text){
    var lastchar = text.split('').pop();
    if (['?','!','.'].indexOf(lastchar) > -1) {
        this.nextSibling.nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(':','');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RRfFr/3/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer and apologies for taking so long to get back round to it. The answer is correct but I incorrectly framed my question and so the solution doesn't quite fit my problem. I have [forked the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielmee/FY5Tp/2/) and, using the info you've supplied, worked out the majority of it.... just can't figure out the syntax for OR operands in an if statement. I ended up solving it using != null :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex :

```
var rx = new RegExp('(?![^<&]+[>;])' + searchString, 'gi');

$('#relatedinfo').html(function (i, html) {
   return html.replace(rx, '<b>$&</b>')
});
```

source : [jQuery to Find/Replace html text when not inside an html tag other than P, DIV, SPAN, TD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087984/jquery-to-find-replace-html-text-when-not-inside-an-html-tag-other-than-p-div)