# Replace HTML content depending on Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I would like to display different HTML elements regarding the status of a variable.

In my HTML file, I have :

```
<div id="dustbinstatus"></div>
```

And in my JS file, I have :

```
if (message.payloadString == "full"){ 
    $('#dustbinstatus').append('<i class="material-icons">delete</i>');
} 

else if (message.payloadString == "empty"){
    $('#dustbinstatus').append('<p> Dustbin ok </p>');
}
```

The message.payloadString variable can change dynamically using websockets.
With this example, it works but it just adds a new line everytime the status changes and I would like a single line to be replaced and change depending on the status.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you !

Olivia

Comment: use html() instead of append()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace HTML string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203611/find-and-replace-html-string-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to replace the contents of the DOM element you have to use jQuery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function (similar to innerHtml of JS) to look like:

```
$('#dustbinstatus').html('<p> Dustbin ok </p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `html()` instead of `append()`

Append is used to append the `Dom element` at the end of existing .

**1st :** you can use `html()`

```
 $('#dustbinstatus').html('<p> Dustbin ok </p>');
```

**2nd :** you can also use `empty()`

```
$('#dustbinstatus').empty().append('<p> Dustbin ok </p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.append` function with `.html`.

`Append` simply explains it self, it will append to what it contains,

`Html` will replace the whole html part inside of the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your previous created line before add your new one. Something like this:

```
$('#dustbinstatus').empty();
if (message.payloadString == "full"){ 
    $('#dustbinstatus').append('<i class="material-icons">delete</i>');
} 

else if (message.payloadString == "empty"){
    $('#dustbinstatus').append('<p> Dustbin ok </p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $('#dustbinstatus').html('');//blank existing dom before append
        if (message.payloadString == "full"){ 
         $('#dustbinstatus').append('<i class="material-icons">delete</i>');
         } else if (message.payloadString == "empty"){
          $('#dustbinstatus').append('<p> Dustbin ok </p>');
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are appending the element, so it append the element at the end, hence you will get a new line everytime.

You can do it by the two ways:

- you can set display to **none** and add a class **active** to display the element instead of appending.

```js
var message = "full";
if (message == "full"){ 
    $('.material-icons').attr('class', 'active');
    $('#dustbinstatus p').attr('class', 'notactive');
} 

else if (message == "empty"){
    $('#dustbinstatus p').attr('class', 'active');
    $('.material-icons').attr('class', 'notactive');
}
```

```css
.active{
  display:block;
}

.notactive{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dustbinstatus">
  <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
  <p> Dustbin ok </p>
</div>
```

- Second way is to use `$(#dustbinstatus).html()` as said in above answers.